# "is modify" should be "is to modify"?

Tags: infinitives

> What genetic modification seeks to do is *modify* crops in a more planned way than is possible by merely selecting healthier seeds or by producing hybrids of successful plants.

It seems that there are two verbs connected - *is* and *modify* - isn't the word *to* missing in front of the word *modify*?

What are the rules to emit one if this is grammatically correct?

Comment: The sentence should be simplified: _Genetic modification seeks to modify crops in a more planned way than is possible by merely selecting healthier seeds or by producing hybrids of successful plants._ The whole "What X seeks to do is..." part clutters the sentence and leads to the awkwardness you point out.

Answer (score 5):

The *to* can be included, but it doesn't have to be. It's implied; *what [x] seeks to do is* ***(to do)*** *[y]*. So yes, it *seeks to modify crops*, but the *to* is implied from the earlier construction and so isn't grammatically necessary here.  But you can write it that way if you wish.